# Error installing R package - Kernsmooth

Tags: r

I am getting error while installing package KernSmooth. How can I install this pacakge ?

Getting warning messages on not able to access index for repository and one with package not available. Below are example warning message-

> Warning: unable to access index for repository
>   http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/src/contrib Warning message: package
>   ‘KernSmooth’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

Comment: Are you using install.packages("KernSmooth"), or are you downloading from the folder directly. install.packages("KernSmooth") should work.

Comment: I am using install.packages("KernSmooth")

Comment: Okay I just tried install.packages("KernSmooth"), and it worked for me on both R version 3.1.1 and R version 3.2.0. Perhaps it is because of that warning package 'KernSmooth' is not available (for R version 3.2.1), which is quite strange that a newer version of R would not support it.

Comment: If install.packages doesn't work, perhaps try installing it from github directly using devtools. Not sure if this is the correct KernSmooth: https://github.com/cran/KernSmooth  but if it is then you would need to install devtools (or library(devtools) if you already have it). Then do install_github("cran/KernSmooth")

Comment: Thanks for your response. may be i am being foolish running it in R console. I should run it in RStudio?  just installed RStudio and ran it ..with following error: > install.packages("KernSmooth")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository /src/contrib

Comment: Hmm, I've never run into this problem, so sorry I'm not that helpful right now. This post might be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258639/problem-loading-the-plyr-package since the problem seems similar if not the same as your current one.

Comment: Problem was in my devtools; i installed it properly chaning the CRAM mirror and after that KernSmooth got installed properly. Thanks